# Who is Monkey D Dragon's wife/Luffy's mother?

Tags: one-piece

In around chapter 592-596 of *One Piece*, Buggy the Clown mentioned that Silver Rayleigh is Luffy's uncle. This implies that Rayleigh's sister should be Dragon's wife.

Who is Monkey D Dragon's wife/Luffy's mother?

Answer (score 2):

No mention has yet been made of Luffy's mother at all, the idea of her hasn't even been brought up. Very few characters have been mentioned to have mothers at all for some reason.

In Japanese as in many Asian countries, they use the idea of "Uncle" or "Big brother" differently to in English speaking countries. It just means an older person you respect, and doesn't imply a blood relation at all. By far most likely what happened is Buggy called Rayleigh "Uncle Rayleigh" as Rayleigh used to be his first mate when he was a cabin boy.

So in summary, there is nothing said about Luffy's mother, nor any hints given, and it's incredibly unlikely that Buggy was saying that Rayleigh is Luffy's uncle, which doesn't happen in the manga anyway.

Comment: No you are wrong. SBS in chapter 424 mentions her

Answer (score 2):

In [SBS Volume 44, Chapter 424](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_44#Chapter_424.2C_Page_106), Oda hinted that Luffy's parents would appear in the next volume, Volume 45.

> **D: Oda-sensei!! I have a serious question. Will you ever draw Luffy's parents?** P.N. Mr. Uni, Age 16
>
> O: His parents? Well, I think you will be pleased with the next volume. Get excited!

Comment: Because Oda said they will appear in the **next** volume, people believes it to be [the women smiling at Dragon when he talks about Luffy.](http://www.onepiecesecretcabinet.com/uploads/9/6/8/0/9680655/8436963_orig.jpg?493) Although people believed that to be Sabo before he entered Dressrosa, and his character design doesn't match with Sabo's. So not sure who dad dude is, but the woman is assumed to be his mother.

Comment: @peter That character doesn't look like a woman.. See the abs in the left picture.

Comment: obviously the person in the red circle, not the blue... At the time it came out people believed blue to be sabo (which was proven wrong recently) and red to be his mother (might be true)

Comment: @peter Yeah, the red one maybe.. Let's see.. Thanks for the manga reference :)